# anyone know what changes if any were made to asp.net wizard control in framework 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, controls, wizard

HI,

i would like to know what differences if any there is between the .net framework 3.5 asp.net control compared to the .net 2.0 framework version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None whatsoever.

ASP.Net 3.5 does not introduce any changes to `System.Web.dll`.

The only changes in ASP.Net 3.5 are in the new `System.Web.Extensions.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

Can't improve on SLaks, but if you want to see everything that was [new in .Net 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332048(VS.90).aspx) ...